# Connected components in 3D image and their indices

Tags: c++, c, matlab, image-processing

I have implemented connected components in 3D image in this way.

```
int isSafe(unsigned char *M, int row, int col, int idz, bool *visited, int *size)
{
   return (row >= 0) && (row < size[0]) && (col >= 0) && (col < size[1]) && (idz >= 0) && (idz < size[2]) &&
       (M[idz * size[0]*size[1] + row*size[0] + col] && !visited[idz*size[0]*size[1] + row*size[0] + col]); 
}

void DFS3D(unsigned char *M, bool *visited, stack<int> &s1, stack<int> &s2, stack<int> &s3, vector < vector <int>> &index, int *size)
{
   int count_components_elements = 0;
   vector <int> indexes;

   while(!s1.empty() && !s2.empty() && !s3.empty())
   {
      int row, col, idz;
      row = s1.top();
      s1.pop();
      col = s2.top();
      s2.pop();
      idz = s3.top();
      s3.pop();

      //add index positions to array or vector
      indexes.push_back(count_components_elements);
      indexes.at(count_components_elements)= (idz*size[0]*size[1] + (row)*size[0] + col);
      ++count_components_elements;

      static int rowNbr[] = {-1, 0, 1,  0, 0,  0};
      static int colNbr[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1, 0,  0};
      static int zNbr[] = { 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, -1};

      visited[idz*size[0]*size[1] + row*size[0] + col ] = true;

      for   (int k = 0; k < 6; ++k)
      {         
         if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], idz + zNbr[k], visited, size) )
         {              
             {
                s1.push(row + rowNbr[k]);
                s2.push(col + colNbr[k]);
                s3.push(idz + zNbr[k]);
                visited[(idz + zNbr[k])*size[0]*size[1] + (row + rowNbr[k])*size[0] + col + colNbr[k]] = true;
             }
         }
     }
 }
 index.push_back(indexes);
}


void FindLargestComponent_3D(unsigned char *M, vector < vector <int>> &index, int *size)
{
   stack <int> s1;
   stack <int> s2;
   stack <int> s3;
   bool *visited = new bool[size[0]*size[1]*size[2]];   
   memset(visited, 0, sizeof(bool)*size[0]*size[1]*size[2]);    

   for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; ++i)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; ++j)
         {
            if (M[k*size[0]*size[1] + i*size[0] + j ] && !visited[k*size[0]*size[1] + i*size[0] + j ]) 
            {                   
                s1.push(i);
                s2.push(j);
                s3.push(k);
                DFS3D(M, visited, s1, s2, s3, index, size);                             
            }
         }
    }
 }  
 delete [] visited;
}
```

Where "M" is the image and "index" vector stores indices of points in respective components. This code is working fine to find the largest connected component but it does not find all other components correctly. I am comparing its output with output of matlab function "bwlabeln".

Please check this code and let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Please see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `FindLargestComponent_3D` function, you iterate through the `k`, `i` and `j` variables with:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k) // Pay attention to this line!!
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; ++j)
        {
```

This limits the search to connected components touching the plane `k=1`. Smaller connected components are less likely to have elements in the `k=1` plane so they are also less likely to be found.

To iterate through all the planes in the k dimension, replace the first of these lines with:

```
for (int k = 0; k < size[2]; ++k)
```

In the future, you may want to use the "iterator pattern" to avoid this mistake.

Comment: @Gaurav Great! Also remember to write more comments in your code for yourself and others. Finally, if this answers your question, mark it as accepted. ;)

Comment: sure, now onwards I will write more comments and answer accepted ;)